# XML parsing return nothing

Tags: android, xml-parsing

how i  set **result not found!** when xml response coming like this

```
<JOBS></JOBS>
```

Any help is appreciated.
 Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using to parse?

Comment: i WANT TO DISPLAY RESULT NOT FOUND WHEN XML RESPONSE HAVE NO DATA

Comment: YES I UNDERSTAND – oh, sorry... I'm yelling. What language are you using? Your question is tagged `android`, but you haven't mentioned which parsing library you're looking to use, if any.